# Reflection overload. Populating reflected array for reflected varargs method

Tags: java, reflection

I'm in the middle of a contender for the greatest kludge of all time. I need to use Spring JDBC without ever making reference to it. A custom classloader is providing the context and I need to use reflection to invoke the methods. One such method is [SimpleJdbcCall.declareParameters(SqlParameter ...)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html#declareParameters%28org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter...%29)

My problem is with creating and setting the varargs `SqlParameter` (these instances must be reflected also). I need to shoehorn a single parameter into an array to satisfy the varargs signature.

In the following, class loading is omitted for brevity. But assume `Class<?> simpleJdbcCallClass = SimpleJdbcCall.class`, etc.

```
Constructor sqlOutParameterConstructor =
    sqlOutParameterClass.getConstructor(String.class, int.class);
Object sqlOutParameter = sqlOutParameterConstructor.newInstance(param, type);

Object paramArray = Array.newInstance(sqlParameterArrayClass, 1);
Array.set(paramArray, 0, sqlParameterClass.cast(sqlOutParameter));
// IllegalArgumentException thrown above.
// It is thrown without the call to .cast too.

Method declareParametersMethod = 
    simpleJdbcCallClass.getMethod("declareParameters", sqlParameterArrayClass);
declareParametersMethod.invoke(procedure, paramArray);
```

The exception thrown is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: array element type mismatch
at java.lang.reflect.Array.set(Native Method)
```

The method takes `SqlParameter ...` and I have an instance of a subclass `SqlOutParameter`. Hence I try to cast with `sqlParameterClass.cast(sqlOutParameter)`. The exception is thrown with or without this casting.

Debugging I can confirm that `paramArray` is an `SqlParameter[]` and `sqlParameterClass.cast(sqlOutParameter)` is an `SqlOutParamter` (not `SqlParameter` as cast). I suspect this may be the problem.

Comment: Just curious but I'd love to know the story behind this

Comment: I undertook a major refactor several months ago converting use of SQLExecutor to Spring 3 JDBC (to get around crippling race conditions). Our app resides within a vendor framework that bundles Spring 1. Some of the signatures in Spring JDBC have changed over those versions. This led to MethodNotFoundExceptions, or similar at runtime. While we wait for vendor to upgrade to Spring 3, I am hacking a dynamic load of Spring 3 JDBC for our DAOs only. Happy happy, joy joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
Object paramArray = Array.newInstance(sqlParameterArrayClass, 1);
```

Specifically, you don't tell us what `sqlParameterArrayClass` is, but based on the name I'm guessing that is the class of the array type.  In fact, it needs to be the class of the array element; see the javadoc for the [`newInstance(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29) methods.

Comment: Also the call to `Class.cast()` is probably unnecessary, don't you think?

Comment: Yes that was the issue. And the cast was unnecessary (it was part of my troubleshooting, as described in the question).